# Stopping a While Loop with '\0'

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop, char

I am having trouble with stopping a while loop when a char array reaches '\0'. I understand that this is the always the last element of any char array and so I do not understand why the code below never ends the loop. Any help would is appreciated.

```
char randomString[] = "testSTRING";

int counter = 0;
while (randomString[counter] != '\0')
    cout << "test";
```

Comment: Your `counter` isn't actually counting anything. It's always zero.

Comment: well this is embarrasing... thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
char randomString[] = "testSTRING";

int counter = 0;

while (randomString[counter++] != '\0')`

    cout << "test";
```